# I have to disconnect/reconnect network cable to access Internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, internet, modem, ubuntu-16.04

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and connect my machine alongside other machines by using a `Hub` to a modem to use Internet. Today I encounter with a problem:

Other machine can connect to the Internet; but I cannot access web (`Server Not Found` error on browser and `ping: unknown host google.com` as result of `$ ping google.com` in terminal), unless after doing disconnecting/re-connecting network cable. But this way only works for a few seconds up to 2 minutes. Although my Android device can connect to the web continuously without any problem through `WiFi`.

Also I connected my machine directly to the modem and even changed the network  (Ethernet) cable. But result was the same.

What causes this problem and how I can solve that?

**Edit1**

I can open `192.168.1.1` from my machine but ***cannot*** login; although it is possible to do that from my other machines.

**Edit2**

- `/ect/resolv.conf` only contains `nameserver 127.0.1.1` (but that file is a link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`)
- the result of `$ nmcli device show $ethernet | grep DNS` is:

  - IP4.DNS[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2okyG.png):                             8.8.8.8
  - IP4.DNS[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1RLd.png):                             4.4.4.4
    -`ping 8.8.8.8` works always
- Both `$ dig 8.8.8.8 google.com` and `$ dig 4.4.4.4 google.com` work when I can access web ; but when problem occurs, I get "`;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`"

**Edit3**

It seems that my machine automatically changes used connection from `Internet` (which is used to access web) to `virbr0` which causes problem:

When I can access web:
[image]

When problem occurs:
[image]

**Edit4**

Result of `$ ip route show` when I can access & cannot access the web:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1  proto static  metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.50  metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Comment: You can connect to the router but not login, yet you can on other PC's? Curious, I would be looking for a second router, that could explain all of your issues.

Comment: What is the virtual bridge for?

Comment: Next step is doing `ip route show` in both cases.

Comment: @xenoid I think `virbr0` must be created and used by `VirtualBox`.

Comment: @xenoid Result of `$ ip route show` in both cases are same. I added result to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Likely a DNS problem..

- check that your `/ect/resolv.conf` only contains `nameserver 127.0.1.1`,
- issue `nmcli device show $ethernet | grep DNS` to list the nameservers (`$ethernet` is the name of your interface, normally some `enp*`)
- check if you can access these (`ping...`)
- check if they can be used `dig @dnserver somesite.com`

The connection editor lets you to force a DNS in your connection, for instance:

- 8.8.8.8 (Google)
- 208.67.220.220/208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question, please see it again. Also it seems you are sure that the problem is not in about `hardware`s, for example network card. Did I guess true?

Comment: Since it works when you disconnect/reconnect then no too likely tthe hardware. Does disconnecting/reconnecting Ethernet using the systray applet also fixes (temporarily) the problem? Otherwise, look in /var/log/syslog around the time you loose the DNS resolution.  Also, does it work if you connect to a totally different network (or not using the hub) ? Is everything in DHCP without any possibilty that two machines get the same IP address?

Comment: I checked my connection and `/var/log/syslog`. Now I edited my question please see it again.